# How to add subdomain to Google Oauth API authorized domain?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm settings my Google APi manager for using as OAuth2.0 authorizations and cant to add subdomen to *authorized domen* fields.  If I write **base.site-demo.com** the **base** part automatically cut and only  site-demo.com added. 
Is it possible to add subdomen this way?